# Database: Best performance way to query geo location data?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, performance

I have a MySQL database. I store homes in the database and perform literally just 1 query against the database, ***but I need this query to be performed super fast***, and that's to return all homes within a square box geo latitude & longitude.

```
SELECT * FROM homes 
WHERE geolat BETWEEN ??? AND ???
AND geolng BETWEEN ??? AND ???
```

How is the best way for me to store my geo data so that I can perform this query of displaying all home within the geolocation box the quickest?

Basically:

- Am I using the best SQL statement to perform this query the quickest?
- Does any other method exist, maybe not even using a database, for me to query the fastest way a result of homes within a boxed geolocation bounds?

In case it helps, I've include my database table schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homes` (
  `home_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `address` varchar(128) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sqft` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `year_built` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `geolat` decimal(10,6) default NULL,
  `geolng` decimal(10,6) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`home_id`),
  KEY `geolat` (`geolat`),
  KEY `geolng` (`geolng`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  ;
```

**UPDATE**

I understand spatial will factor in the curvature of the earth but I'm most interested in returning geo data the FASTEST. Unless these spatial database packages somehow return data faster, please don't recommend spatial extensions. Thanks

**UPDATE 2**

Please note, no one below has truly answered the question. I'm really looking forward to any assistance I might receive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: UTM coordinates are a better choice - the world isn't flat, but UTM incorporates a degree of flattening while Lat/Long doesn't at all.

Comment: I also recommend reading about MySQL's spatial functionality: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html

Comment: Postgres is another spatial capable db alternative, which I would recommend using rather than MySQL: http://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: I understand spatial will factor in the curvature of the earth but I'm most interested in returning geo data the FASTEST

Comment: Even if the data is bad?

Comment: What do you mean, "data is bad"? My application is looking at data from typically no more than 3 miles by 3 miles wide. So the curvature of the earth does not factor in that much

Comment: Did you even look at the link that Ponies gave you for MYSQL Spatial?  It is likely that spatial indexes will indeed help you fetch your data faster as well as be more correct.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-spatial-analysis.html (which is a direct link from the page above)

Comment: ALL, SPATIAL IS NOT FASTER. I am using InnoDB. Per the documentation "InnoDB tables do not support spatial data types before MySQL 5.0.16. As of 5.0.16, InnoDB supports spatial data types, but not indexes on them. "  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html  Why do you keep recommending SPATIAL when the documentation you are providing me to read, and claim that I'm not reading but AM, clearly states that for InnoDB database - not having an index will case for slower queries. Again, my question in hand is HOW DO I PERFORM THE QUICKEST QUERY FOR GEO DATA ?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but it's frustrating when you claim I'm not reading the documentation you link too and when I read it, it clearly state the OPPOSITE of what you claim. It makes me think, are you even reading the documentation you are linking too yourself?

Comment: UTM would be awkward unless the area of interest is less than approximately 6 degrees of longitude wide and preferably only one side of the equator. If the area is wider than this, you need to specify a zone and the coordinates will be discontinuous across zone boundaries. At the equator, the y coordinate approaches zero from the north, but 10000000 when approached from the south.

For areas with large extent in both latitude and longitude, the easiest coordinate system is latitude and longitude. You just have to accept the issues that come with spherical coordinates.

Comment: HankW could you change your question topic to include your performance needs somehow to make your goal more explicit? of course "best" depends on the specific situation :) might also generate more views.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is faster than what you already do or not (I got here by accident), but Google Maps has an example of creating a shop locator that seems to do exactly what you are doing:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#findnearsql Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 14):

There is a good paper on MySQL geolocation performance [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL).

*EDIT* Pretty sure this is using fixed radius. Also I am not 100% certain the algorithm for calculating distance is the most advanced (i.e. it'll "drill" through Earth).

What's significant is that the algorithm is cheap to give you a ball park limit on the number of rows to do proper distance search.

---

The algorithm pre-filters by taking candidates in a square around the source point, then calculating the distance in **miles**.

Pre-calculate this, or use a stored procedure as the source suggests:

```
# Pseudo code
# user_lon and user_lat are the source longitude and latitude
# radius is the radius where you want to search
lon_distance = radius / abs(cos(radians(user_lat))*69);
min_lon = user_lon - lon_distance;
max_lon = user_lon + lon_distance;
min_lat = user_lat - (radius / 69);
max_lat = user_lat + (radius / 69);
```

```
SELECT dest.*,
  3956 * 2 * ASIN(
    SQRT(
      POWER(
        SIN(
          (user_lat - dest.lat) * pi() / 180 / 2
        ), 2
      ) + COS(
        user_lat * pi() / 180
      ) * COS(
        dest.lat * pi() / 180
      ) * POWER(
        SIN(
          (user_lon - dest.lon) * pi() / 180 / 2
        ), 2
      )
    )
  ) as distance
FROM dest
WHERE 
  dest.lon between min_lon and max_lon AND
  dest.lat between min_lat and max_lat
HAVING distance < radius
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It appears that using the stored procedure on slide #14 is promising but it's unclear to me if that assumes a fixed radius. Do you know if the radius is fixed or not? I want to be able to pass in the box corner (radius)

Comment: I need to be able to pass in as an argument the boxed radius. Do you think I can then use the linked document as such then?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and wrote a 3 part blogpost. This was faster than the geo index.

[Intro](http://evertpot.com/229), [Benchmark](http://evertpot.com/230), [SQL](http://evertpot.com/231)

Comment: Evert, how do you implemented Morton (z-value)? You're second article just jumps in and says nothing about how you computed the value

Comment: The third one does actually. There's a stored procedure

Comment: What I don't understand is that when I perform the SELECT, how do I know what the morton value is to select on?

Comment: Good question. You should make sure that for every row in your table, you also store this morton value. You can do this with an AFTER INSERT (along with AFTER UPDATE).

When you SELECT you can simply do a BETWEEN getGeoMorton(lat1,lng1) AND getGeoMorton(lat2,lng2).

Because the morton select will be an approximation, and can include a lot of items outside the area, you must also add a standard where clause for just the latitude and longitude bounding box.

The real trick is that you are now using a BTREE for much smaller areas rather than JUST the latitude or longitude.

Comment: And that's why SO answers should include relevant quotes... links are dead.

Comment: Criticism still partly stands though; you should quote a few relevant sections from your post. At least mention Morton Number or something so that if/when those links die again, we can at least search for info.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I also don't care enough. This answer is from '09.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to go for performance you can define bounding boxes for your data and map the pre-compute bounding boxes to your objects on insertion and use them later for queries.

If the resultsets are reasonably small you could still do accuracy corrections in the application logic (easier to scale horizontal than a database) while enabling to serve accurate results.

Take a look at Bret Slatkin's [geobox.py](http://code.google.com/p/mutiny/source/browse/trunk/geobox.py) which contains great documentation for the approach.

I would still recommend checking out PostgreSQL and [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) in comparison to MySQL if you intend to do more complex queries in the foreseeable future.

Comment: And this is exactly why we should not use links on StackOverflow. Your link is broken.

Comment: @Sandor thanks for letting me know, I've adapted the answer and removed the dead link.

Answer (score 2):

A very good alternative is **MongoDB** with its [**Geospatial Indexing**](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).

Answer (score 1):

The indices you are using are indeed B-tree indices and support the `BETWEEN` keyword in your query. This means that the optimizer is able to use your indices to find the homes within your "box". It does however not mean that it will always use the indices. If you specify a range that contains too many "hits" the indices will not be used.

Comment: So, would using min_latitude >= ??? max_latitude <= ??? be better instead of using BETWEEN?

Comment: From the manual: This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max)

Comment: what do you mean if there are too many "hits" the indexes won't be used? I don't understand

Comment: If you specify an area that contains too many records the index wont be used.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with your current approach there is one change you should make,
Rather than indexing geolat and geolong separately you should have a composite index:

```
KEY `geolat_geolng` (`geolat`, `geolng`),
```

Currently your query will only be taking advantage of one of the two indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick I've used with some success is to create round-off regions.  That is to say, if you have a location that's at 36.12345,-120.54321, and you want to group it with other locations which are within a half-mile (approximate) grid box, you can call its region 36.12x-120.54, and all other locations with the same round-off region will fall in the same box.

Obviously, that doesn't get you a clean radius, i.e. if the location you're looking at is closer to one edge than another.  However, with this sort of a set-up, it's easy enough to calculate the eight boxes that surround your main location's box.  To wit:

```
[36.13x-120.55][36.13x-120.54][36.13x-120.53]
[36.12x-120.55][36.12x-120.54][36.12x-120.53]
[36.11x-120.55][36.11x-120.54][36.11x-120.53]
```

Pull all the locations with matching round-off labels and then, once you've got them out of the database, you can do your distance calculations to determine which ones to use.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 5.7 mysql can use geoindex like ST_Distance_Sphere() and ST_Contains() wich improve performances.

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty fast. My only concern would be that it would use an index to get all the values within 3 miles of the latitude, then filter those for values within 3 miles of the longitude. If I understand how the underlying system works, you can only use one INDEX per table, so either the index on lat or long is worthless.

If you had a large amount of data, it *might* speed things up to give every 1x1 mile square a unique logical ID, and then make an additional restriction on the SELECT that (area="23234/34234" OR area="23235/34234" OR ... ) for all the squares around your point, then force the database to use that index rather than the lat and long. Then you'll only be filtering much less square miles of data.

Comment: One index per table? Do you confuse it with primary key?

Comment: I mean that when you do a SELECT it only uses one index per table in the SELECT.

Comment: Ah.. That's a good point, but do you think creating a composite index would make a difference?

Comment: A (more sophisticated) composite index is what spatial indexes do and it is faster if there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Homes?  You probably won't even have ten thousand of them.  Just use an in-memory index like [STRTree](http://www.vividsolutions.com/Jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/index/strtree/STRtree.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a separate table 'GeoLocations' that has a primary key of ('geolat','geolng') and has a column that holds the home_id if that particular geolocation happens to have a home. This should allow the optimizer to search for a range of geo locations that will be sorted on disk for a list of home_ids. You could then perform a join with your 'homes' table to find information about those home_ids.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GeoLocations` (
`geolat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
`geolng` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
`home_id` int(10) NULL
PRIMARY KEY  (`geolat`,`geolng`)
);

SELECT GL.home_id
FROM GeoLocations GL
INNER JOIN Homes H
 ON GL.home_id = H.home_id
WHERE GL.geolat between X and Y
 and GL.geolng between X and Y
```