# How do I paginate items queried with mysql but sorted with PHP usort function?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, usort

I do a query to fetch all restaurants in my mysql db.
After that, I sort these on distance to the user with the PHP usort function, based on their lat/lng coordinates.

What's the most efficient way to paginate the usorted array, without needing to do a query and usort on all items each new paginated page?

Comment: Can you do the sorting in MySQL?

Comment: Don't think so, I use the Haversine formula to calculate the distance between to pairs of lat/lng coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this in PHP. MySQL will do a much better job sorting your results set.

There's a paper [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) about doing this in MySQL, which is referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813460/database-best-performance-way-to-query-geo-location-data).

Regardless of which formula you're using, you should be able to do this with MySQL, even if you have to used [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html).

Comment: Thanks! Looks exactly like where I'm looking for!