# Should I use MySQL Geo-Spatial data types for vector graphics

Tags: mysql, svg, geospatial, vector-graphics

I am working on a project where I need to store and do computations on SVG paths and points (preferably in MySQL). I need to be able to quickly query whether a point lies within a path. MySQL's Geo-spatial features seems to support this kind of query with the [ST_Within](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-within) function.

However, I have found 2 opposing claims regarding whether MySQL's Geo-spatial functionality takes into account the 'curvature of the earth'. ["I understand spatial will factor in the curvature of the earth"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813460/database-best-performance-way-to-query-geo-location-data) and ["all calculations are performed assuming Euclidean (planar) geometry as opposed to the geocentric system (coordinates on the Earth's surface)"](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/exploring-mysql-5.7s-geo-spatial-functions.html). So, my question is which of the claims is true and whether/how does this effect me?

Also, any general advice on whether I should be taking this approach of storing SVG objects as MySQL Geo-spatial data types is welcome.

Comment: use postgis where you are in full control of wether the curvature is used or not. It has two type geometry and geography

Comment: and also postgresql has ST_DWithin which is lacking in mysql and it's the real mccoy

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for the advice. Can you describe how the support for ST_DWithin is going to be a concern in my use-case? [ST_Within](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-within) seems to be enough for my use-case. Or, is it not?

Comment: ST_DWithin is if the object is within a given distance from the other. ST_within means a is within b. Which means for each object you need to build an envelope. If you are comparing data in two tables or columns this doesn't scale

Comment: That's right but if I only need to be able to query whether a point lies within a polygon and never need to query whether 2 polygons intersect, should that concern me?

Comment: ST_Dwithin is not about intersection.

Comment: It's about the distances between polygons, right? The minimum distance between any points lying on 2 given polygons. I don't need to be able to compute that.

Comment: not just polygons any geometry. yes, sounds like you don't need this function, but I urge you to do some more research before commiting to mysql. Postgis is hte most complete open source implementation of a spatial database.

Comment: Yes, I'm still researching this. However, it's possible that my choices end up being using MySQL Geo-spatial or not using Geo-spatial at all and just using the standard MySQL datatypes and doing the computations with stored procedures/functions.

Comment: definitely not choice #3 that's reinventing bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further research, it seems that the second claim is true. That is, all computations in MySQL are done without regards to the curvature of the earth and just assumes a flat plane. References:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/
- http://www.programering.com/a/MTNwQjMwATI.html
- http://blog.karmona.com/index.php/2010/11/01/the-geospatial-cloud/

General advice on whether I should be taking this approach of storing SVG objects as MySQL Geo-spatial data types is still very much welcome.